# Laravel eloquent : Filter and fetch data from three tables with relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

In my app I have three tables: `products`, `categories`, and `subcategories`.

1. `product` *hasMany* `category`
2. `category` *hasMany* `subcategory` (with `subcategories` production date)

I would like to get all products' names with `category`'s name, `subcategory`'s name, and `date` filtered by `subcategory`'s date `('dateProd', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))`.

I made these relations below:

##### `product` (model and table)

```
public function categorie()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categorie::class');
}
```

```
$table->string('name');
```

##### `Categorie` (model and table)

```
public function product(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

public function subcategory(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subcategorie::class);
}
```

```
$table->string('name');
$table->foreignId('porduct_id')->constrained();
```

##### `Subcategorie` (model and table)

```
public function category(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

```
$table->string('name');
$table->date('dateProd');
$table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
```

##### In the view

```html
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product->name }}
    @foreach($products->category as $category)
        {{ $category->name }}
        @foreach($category->subcategory as $subcategory)
            {{ $subcategory->name }}
            {{ $subcategory->dateProd }}
        @endforeach
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

You can use `whereHas` to filter only the products that have the required subcategories

```php
Product::query()
    ->whereHas('categorie.subcategory', function ($query) {
        $query->where('dateProd', '<=', date('Y-m-d'));
    })
    ->with(['categorie.subcategory'])
    ->get();
```